# How the view and viewcontroller hooked?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cannot find where the view and viewcontroller get hooked? Is it in the xib file?

I learned that each viewcontroller can control several views, but where are those two get hooked?

Comment: If you're using Storyboards, click on the view controller and view the properties. It will show the ViewController that it's using. If you don't specify it, it defaults to your regular controller. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUbJXR9XlY0

Comment: What do you mean "hooked"?

Comment: He means "hook" as in connected together.

Comment: @h4labs, we'll let the OP answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the whole ViewController Programming Guide if you have doubts like that:

[ViewController Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1)

In case you want to jump right to your issue, check this section:

[Resource Managment in ViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)

You can find a nice graph explaining where the views are created and linked in the ViewController:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A `ViewController` is just that, a class to manage the `UIViews` (there will be many) that it contains.  The main view is automatically wired up for you and you are responsible for wiring up all the other views you add.  Keep in mind that `UIButtons`, `UILabels`, `UIViews`, etc are all objects that inherit from `UIView`.

Like Antonio indicated, start with the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1):

Answer (score 0):

The view controller has its own view. Each child view (subview) view has a parent view (superview). You can nest views inside of views. In your case, the top view in the hierarchy is the view controller's view.

At design time, you can add a child view to any view in Interface Builder by simply dragging a new view onto the parent view. You can also adjust the view hierarchy from the Document Outline in Interface Builder.

**When creating a view hierarchy in Interface Builder, the view hierarchy is stored in the *.xib* file.**

At run time, your views are instantiated from the information in the *.xib file*, and each child view's `superview` property points to its parent view. Each view also has a `subviews` property that lists each of its child views.

You can add a view to any other view at run time by instantiating a new view and passing it to the parent view's `addSubview` method. Obviously, once instantiated, you can alter the view hierarchy by setting the `superview` and `subviews` properties and calling related methods.